# Using an existing Oauth provider to consume my API?

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

From what I understand about Oauth, a user logs in to Facebook, then Facebook provides my application with an access token that I can use to make calls to Facebook's API. Can I use that same access token to authenticate calls to my own API?

What would this look like in terms of storing and accessing user data for my own app such as personal settings and resources?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use that same access token to authenticate calls to my own API?

You technically can. Token is just a *random* identifier that uniquely identifies a user within an application in the OAuth provider.

> What would this look like in terms of storing and accessing user data for my own app such as personal settings and resources?

You need to store as much information as you need to uniquely identify a user and an application (if you support them) this token belongs to.